# Covering of schemes and flatness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness, etale-covers

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a finite surjective morphism of quasi-projective schemes over $\mathbb{C}$, $X$ is reduced and $Y$ is integral. Suppose that there exists an integer $n$ such that for every *closed* point $y \in Y$, the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ is reduced and consists of $n$ distinct closed points. Is it true that $f$ is flat?

Comment: I suspect there is a ground field. Is it assumed algebraically closed?

Comment: Yes. You can also assume characteristic zero.

Comment: The normalization of a cuspidal curve is a bijective finite map which is not flat.

Comment: Hartshorne also assumes $Y$ is regular.

Comment: Sasha: Sorry, my mistake. I will remove the comment.

Comment: @Achinger: I was reading the nice discussion on cuspidal curves and its normalization in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40960/is-the-normalization-map-bijective May be I am wrong, but it seems that the normalization is not bijective over $\mathbb{C}$. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: The normalization of the cuspidal curve is actually bijective (in fact, it is a homeomorphism), but the fibre over the cusp is *not* reduced.

Comment: @Polizzi: So, the cuspidal example is not a counterexample to the above statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply Hartshorne, Exercise II.5.8 to $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: @Starr: Thank you very much for the answer. I have a small question. In this exercise Hartshorne considers dimesion of pullback of coherent sheaves to *points* on $Y$. Are these points necessarily closed? As one can see, for example in the proof of III. Theorem 9.9 of Hartshorne, we see that he does not necessarily restrict to closed points, when he says *points*.

Comment: @user46578.  You should read the rest of the section, or maybe just the rest of the exercise.  The rank function is upper semicontinuous.  So if you know the rank is constant at all closed points, then you know the rank is constant at all points.